# Blazor page not firing OnAfterRenderAsync event when hit indirectly using CascadingAppState

Tags: blazor, local-storage, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor app (Server side) that is using CascadingAppState to pass credentials between pages.  The app works great when I run it from the index page, but when I try to go directly to an inside page, the  OnAfterRenderAsync event on the CascadingAppState.razor page is never hit.  For example, htpp://localhost works fine.  When I try http://localhost/products/1785 the page does load and the event doesn't fire.  When I try to go to the same inside URL from a page once hitting the index page, everything works fine.  I tried placing the blazor.js tag in different places, but still no luck.  Any ideas?  Below are the 2 main pages.  Thanks in advance

CascadingAppState:

`

```
@implements IAppState
@inject ILocalStorageService LocalStorageService
@using CommercialSalesPortal.Models
@inject Radzen.DialogService dialogService
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>
 event on the
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    private string Caller = "";

    public int TimeToLiveInSeconds { get; set; } = 60;
    public DateTime LastAccessed { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public void SetProperty(ComponentBase caller, string PropertyName,
                            object PropertyValue, bool SaveChanges = true)
    {
        try
        {
            var prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName);
            if (prop != null)
            {
                this.Caller = caller.GetType().Name;
                prop.SetValue(this, PropertyValue);
                if (SaveChanges)
                    this.SaveChanges();
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    private string message = "";
    public string Message
    {
        get => message;
        private set
        {
            message = value;
            if (Caller == "Toolbar")
            {
                // The Toolbar component changed the AppState Message property
            }
        }
    }

    private bool enabled = false;
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get => enabled;
        private set
        {
            enabled = value;
        }
    }

    private int counter = 0;
    public int Counter
    {
        get => counter;
        private set
        {
            counter = value;
            if (Caller == "Counter")
            {
                // The Counter page changed the AppState Counter property
            }
        }
    }
    private List<PriceRequestAccountUsage> usagelist = null;
    public List<PriceRequestAccountUsage> UsageList { get; set; }

    private UserObject currentuser = null;
    public UserObject CurrentUser
    {
        get => currentuser;
        private set
        {
            currentuser = value;
        }
    }
    private string encryptedcreidentials = "";
    public string EncryptedCredentials
    {
        get => encryptedcreidentials;
        private set
        {
            encryptedcreidentials = value;
            if (Caller == "Toolbar")
            {
                // The Toolbar component changed the AppState Message property
            }
        }
    }
    private async void DialogPopupClosed(dynamic theResult)
    {
        if (theResult != null && theResult == true)
        {
            //NavManager.NavigateTo("index");
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender) // do this only once
        {
            // Get the JSON data
            var json = await LocalStorageService.GetItemAsStringAsync("AppStateJson");
            dialogService.OnClose += DialogPopupClosed;
            if (json != null && json != "")
            {
                // Deserialize to AppStateData
                var appStateData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppStateData>(json);
                // Are we within the time window?
                if (DateTime.Now <= appStateData.LastAccessed
                    .AddDays(appStateData.TimeToLiveInSeconds))
                {
                    // Yes! use our own SetProperty method to set our property values
                    var properties = appStateData.GetType().GetProperties();
                    foreach (var property in properties)
                    {
                        var type = property.PropertyType;
                        var value = property.GetValue(appStateData);
                        SetProperty(this, property.Name, value, false);
                    }
                }
                // Re-render
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EncryptedCredentials))
                {
                    var splitCredentials = CommercialSalesPortal.Web.Code.EncryptionFactory.DecryptString(EncryptedCredentials).Split("|");
                    CurrentUser = CPS.Data.Code.UserFactory.ValidateUser(splitCredentials[0], splitCredentials[1]);

                    EncryptedCredentials = CommercialSalesPortal.Web.Code.EncryptionFactory.EncryptString("JoshAdmin|Password123!|" + DateTime.Now);
                    SetProperty(this, "EncryptedCredentials", EncryptedCredentials);
                    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                }
                else
                {
                    //CurrentUser = CPS.Data.Code.UserFactory.ValidateUser("JoshAdmin", "Password123!");
                    //await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                    PopLogin();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                PopLogin();
            }
        }
    }
    public void PopLogin()
    {

        SetProperty(this, "CurrentUser", new CommercialSalesPortal.Models.UserObject());
        dialogService.Open<CPS.Web.Pages.LogIn>("LogIn", null, new Radzen.DialogOptions() { Width = "800px", Height = "570px", Resizable = true, Draggable = true });
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        LastAccessed = DateTime.Now;
        var appstate = (IAppState)this;
        var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(appstate);
        LocalStorageService.SetItemAsStringAsync("AppStateJson", json);
    }
}
```

MainLayout:

```
`@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject Radzen.DialogService dialogService
@inject Radzen.NotificationService notificationService
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@inject Web.Data.ICookieFactory cookieFactory

@using CPS.Web.Code
<div class="page">
    <div class="content">
        <RadzenDialog />
        <RadzenNotification />
        @if (AppState != null && AppState.CurrentUser != null && AppState.CurrentUser.UserProfileKey > 0)
        {
        }
    </div>
</div>
@code
{
    [CascadingParameter] public CascadingAppState AppState { get; set; }
    private string JumpToRequestNumber = string.Empty;
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    { }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        dialogService.OnClose += ReloadPage;
    }
    public void ReloadPage(dynamic theResult)
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    private void RefreshMe()
    {
        if (AppState.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            JS.InvokeAsync<object>("SetActiveNavTab");
            CreateUserCookie();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
    public void PopSettings()
    {
        dialogService.Open<CPS.Web.Pages.Settings>("Settings", null, new Radzen.DialogOptions() { Width = "800px", Height = "570px", Resizable = true, Draggable = true });
    }
    public void PopLogin()
    {
        dialogService.Open<CPS.Web.Pages.LogIn>("LogIn", null, new Radzen.DialogOptions() { Width = "800px", Height = "570px", Resizable = true, Draggable = true });
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    private void JumpToRequest()
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/PriceRequest/" + JumpToRequestNumber);
    }
    private void PopBugReport()
    {
        dialogService.Open<CPS.Web.Pages.Popup.ReportBug>("Report Bug", null,
        new Radzen.DialogOptions() { Width = "700px", Height = "650px" });
    }
    private void SayThanks()
    {
        try
        {
            CommercialSalesPortal.Web.Code.EmailFactory.SendEmail(CommercialSalesPortal.Code.Constants.ThanksEmailReportTo, GenerateMessage(), "New Thank You", CPS.Entity.Constants.EmailFromAddress, string.Empty);
            NotificationMessage theMesage = new NotificationMessage { Style = "position: absolute; left: -1000px;", Severity = NotificationSeverity.Success, Summary = "Your thanks was sent successully!", Detail = "Much Appreciated", Duration = 4000 };
            notificationService.Notify(theMesage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            NotificationMessage theMesage = new NotificationMessage { Style = "position: absolute; left: -1000px;", Severity = NotificationSeverity.Error, Summary = "There was an error sending your thanks: ", Detail = ex.Message, Duration = 40000 };
            notificationService.Notify(theMesage);
        }
    }
    private string GenerateMessage()
    {
        return "A new thanks message was sent from " + AppState.CurrentUser.DisplayName;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets values for the price request cookie
    /// </summary>
    private void WritePricingCookie()
    {
        LocalFunctions.ConfigureDependencyInjections(cookieFactory);
        LocalFunctions.WriteDataToCookie(Entity.Constants.PriceRequestCookieName, JumpToRequestNumber);
    }
}
`
```

Comment: A little confused???  Where is `CascadingAppState` used?  However, you should **NEVER** cascade a component instance.  Why?  1. You're exposing lots of functionality that won't work as expected [which is what I suspect is happening here] 2. You don't control a Component's lifecycle (The Renderer does).  Your cascaded instance may not be the "live" instance and may have been "Disposed".  Create and cascade State/Context objects.  `AppState` for instance.

Comment: And also can't you use `AuthenticationState` with a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` for your credentials?

Comment: I'm using this to pass not just user information but list information from page to page.  I followed the example Carl Franklin gave (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WPuGwxZKIA).  I declare the CascadingAppState component on each page (    [CascadingParameter] public CascadingAppState AppState { get; set; }).  Like I said, once I hit the index page the first time it works fine.  It's only when trying to hit an inside page directly.

Comment: I've taken a quick look at the UTube example and I disagree with Carl on cascading the `CascadingAppState` component for the reasons given above.  I would break out the data into an `AppState` class and `CascadingAppState` would simple cascade an instance of `AppState` managed by `CascadingAppState`.  On your issue, you are doing something on `Index` that your aren't doing on say `Counter`.  You need to figure out what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  I noticed it was throwing an error when tying to talk to the Blazor.server.js script.  I added a  to my MainLayout page and it works perfectly now.  Thank you